# Unable to dual boot Ubuntu and Windows 10 on separate SSDs

Tags: boot, dual-boot, grub2, uefi

I've got two SSDs, and I want to run Windows 10 from one and Ubuntu 19.10 from the other. (I've tried this with 19.04 with the same result)

My laptop is a Dell Precision 5530. I've disabled secure boot, UEFI is still on, chosen AHCI instead of RAID and turned off fast startup in Windows.

Windows 10 is already installed on sda, and I'm trying to install Ubuntu on nvme0n1.

The install goes fine, but when I get to the boot menu, and select either Ubuntu or the first partition of the 2nd hard drive, booting fails.

If I take out the Windows hard drive from my laptop, I boot directly into Ubuntu, no problem.

[image]

I tried to use boot-repair from a live usb, but when I tried to apply any changes it just complained that I had to run the command from a live usb, which I was actually doing. I did manage to get a boot info script from boot-repair, located in this pastebin: http://paste.ubuntu.com/p/Mf3V8ymzw3/.

Answer (score 1):

> The install goes fine, but when I get to the boot menu, and select either Ubuntu or the first partition of the 2nd hard drive, booting fails.
>
> If I take out the Windows hard drive from my laptop, I boot directly into Ubuntu, no problem.

I don't know what "the boot menu" is supposed to signify in this case, but since you can boot Ubuntu without issue when the Windows disk is removed, I'd say this indicates that your Windows disk "takes over" the responsibility of booting, which is your first issue. So I would, in general terms, to the following:

- Go into the BIOS and make sure that your Ubuntu disk is designated as the primary boot disk. If it is, you should notice this by the fact that Ubuntu *always* boots, there's no way to boot Windows because that disk is ignored.
- When your Ubuntu disk is designated as the primary boot disk, make sure your Windows disk is actively plugged in and run `update-grub` in Ubuntu. To learn more about `update-grub` [see this page](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/xenial/man8/update-grub.8.html).

Hopefully the end-result should be that `update-grub` detects your Windows disk, adds it to the GRUB boot menu, and the next time you boot you'll have a GRUB screen that lets you choose between Ubuntu, or the Windows disk.

If you want to set one of them as the default etc. there are many configuration options for GRUB that you can look into.

Comment: Unfortunately, that doesn't help. The boot sequence was already like shown in the picture in my original post. If I try to move the third option first, booting fails over and over and over.

Comment: I just made it work by going to Bios Setup, adding a new boot option, finding grubx64.efi, and booting from that boot option. :)